# flutter problem with longpress and dimissable

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement Dismiss Widget feature like whatsapp voice note delete.
When mic button is in state of long press i am unable activate dismiss on the icon. I want to push the container on drag.

```
GestureDetector(
                  
                  onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails d) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showAudioControls = false;
                      _micSize = 24.0;
                      _startRecording = false;
                    });
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      
                      _showAudioControls = true;
                      _micSize = _micMaxSize;
                      _startRecording = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: AnimatedSize(
                    vsync: this,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    child: Container(
                      width: _micSize == 44 ? 60 : 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.mic,
                        size: _micSize, //34
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
GestureDetector(
  // ...
  
  onLongPressStart: (_) {
    // start recording
  },
  onLongPressEnd: (_) {
    // stop recording
  },
  onLongPressMoveUpdate: (details) {
    Offset localPosition = details.localPosition;

    // update your container position with offset
  },
),
```